# How to search email with Jämsä for Jämsän in Thunderbird?

Tags: regular-expression, search, thunderbird

Finnish language has many many endings, but I cannot search easily the base word, etc by `Jämsä`. 
For instance, searching `Jämsä` will not give `Jämsän` in the basic Thunderbird search. 
A basic regex search would help here.

A differential solution is to use Evolution where the basic search `Jämsä` returns messages with contents/title `Jämsän`, but one shortcoming is no offline use with IMAP as described in the thread [How to setup Evolution IMAP for Offline use?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/403881/16920)

OS: Debian 9.1
Thunderbird version: default